# Is there universal way to check mac&ip for multiple printers?

Tags: printer, ip-address, mac-address

As in title, is there any good way to check mac and ip addresses on multiple printers without connecting to all the printers.

Running Windows 7 on my workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean by not individually accessing them, then yes, it's possible, but they would still have to be connected to the network. What you need is a network tool to scan for IPs.

Get something like "Angy IP scanner", selected the desired columns (in your case IP, name and MAC) and perform a scan of your network. Such a program will display you a list with all IPs/MACs found.

If you have too many IPs and trouble identifying which one are printers, you can check a list of registered MAC address classes for the printer manufacturer or make some selections based on name.

Also, some manufacturers offer detection tools for their printers, but if you have many types/models then the IP scan is your best choice.